# how to put array data into text file using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

if i use the following code i got data in text file

```
{"title":"sankas","description":"sakars","code":"sanrs"}    
{"title":"test","description":"test","code":"test"}
```

but my code is working on

```
{"title":"sankas","description":"sakars","code":"sanrs"}
```

so i could not add more rows.where i want to change to get correct results.

```
        $info = array();
    $folder_name = $this->input->post('folder_name');
    $info['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
    $info['description'] = $this->input->post('description');
    $info['code'] = $this->input->post('code');
    $json = json_encode($info);
    $file = "./videos/overlay.txt";
    $fd = fopen($file, "a"); // a for append, append text to file

    fwrite($fd, $json);
    fclose($fd);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use php's `file_put_content()` more information here http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

**Update :** 
assuming that the data is correctly being passed. here is what you can do.

```
$info = array();
$folder_name = $this->input->post('folder_name');
$info['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
$info['description'] = $this->input->post('description');
$info['code'] = $this->input->post('code');
$json = json_encode($info);
$file = "./videos/overlay.txt";
//using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content.
file_put_contents ($file, $json, FILE_APPEND);
```

**Update 2:**

if you want to access the value back from the text file. overlay.txt here is what you can do

```
$content = file_get_contents($file);
```

if you want to fetch title, code, and description separately. and if the string is in json then you need to convert it into array first by using.

```
//this will convert the json data back to array
$data = json_decode($json);
```

and to access individual value you can do it like this if you have one row

```
echo $data['title'];
echo $data['code'];
echo $data['description'];
```

if you have multiple rows then you can use php foreach loop

```
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    $key contains the key for example code, title and description
    $value contains the value for the correspnding key
}
```

hope this helps you.

**Update 3:**

do it like this

```
$jsonObjects = file_get_contents('./videos/overlay.txt');
$jsonData = json_decode($jsonObjects);
foreach ($jsonData as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . $value;
    //$key contains the key (code, title, descriotion) and $value contains its corresponding value
}
```

Comment: i am asking correct answer with my code.use use file_put_contents() in my code.

Comment: $string = implode($json);
        file_put_contents("./videos/overlay.txt", $string);    thism is not working

Comment: @Sankar Mvs i did that. and that should work. if i understand you correct then you want to append the json string in the end of file right?

Comment: you are using json_encode already to convert array to json. do you want it to convert into string?

Comment: how to retrive this value     {"title":"asd","description":"asd","code":"asd"}{"title":"sad","description":"sadd","code":"sadd"}

Comment: do you want to fetch the value from the text file? be specific tell me exactly what you want to do.

Comment: from where you want the value. you already have it? do you want the value from existing file? or from the array you want specific value.?

Comment: see my ful code,this is correct or not?why i am asking you only i can get first title value i can not get all title value.http://jsfiddle.net/sankars/t62NB/

Comment: ya...it is showing Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in F:\Software\xampp\htdocs\mine\sankar.php on line 7 in update 3

Comment: can you show what data is being fetched by doing `print_r($jsonData);`

Comment: i think you are giving the wrong path to retrieve it. try `echo $jsonObjects;` and tell me what is being generated.

Comment: echo $jsonObjects; is genereted {"title":"test","description":"test","code":"test"}{"title":"testdddd","description":"testddd","code":"testdd"}

Comment: we can not chat long time .so this is my mail id:sankarnics@gmail.com